# T-SQL and Joins with where conditions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, left-join

If I have multiple left join statements and I have to apply `where` conditions like `x="string1"`, how do I apply them to individual left join statement?

More in a situation like this?

```
SELECT 
W.[ABC],
A.[XYZ]

FROM BLAH1 B0

LEFT JOIN WebUnion W ON B0.ID=W.ID
LEFT JOIN AppUnion A ON B0.ID=A.ID

WHERE WBC is null
AND
WHERE WBC is not null
```

Comment: Put the clause in the `ON` instead of the `WHERE`? You haven't qualified your column `WBC` so we don't know what table it is related to. Also a single query scope can only have one `WHERE`. `AND WHERE` will cause a syntax error.

Comment: Though, defining you want rows where `WBC` has both a `NULL` *and* `NOT NULL` value makes no sense. A value can **never** be both `NULL` and `NOT NULL`; they are by definition complete opposites. If a value is `NULL` it is by definition *not* `NOT NULL`, and likewise is a value is `NOT NULL` it is by definition *not* `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Since your query has some mistakes I write examples in general

```
  Select A.*,B.* from
  (SELECT * FROM t1 where t1.f1="xxx" and ...) as A
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT * FROM t2 where t1.f2="yyy" and ...) as B
  ON A.id = b.fid
```

OR

```
  Select t1.*,t2.* from
  t1
  LEFT JOIN
  t2
  ON t1.id = t2.fid and t1.f1="xxx" and t1.f2="yyy"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
W.[ABC],
A.[XYZ]

FROM BLAH1 B0

LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM WebUnion WHERE WBC IS NULL) W ON B0.ID=W.ID
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM AppUnion WHERE WBC IS NOT NULL) A ON B0.ID=A.ID
```